# Spliting values based on condition in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

Look at the below code or this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aAy6L/1/)

```
var arr = ["[Dim1].[Mem1].&[1]",
           "[Dim2].[Mem1].&[2]",
           "[Dim1].[Mem1].&[5]",
           "[Dim2].[Mem1].&[77]",
           "[Dim2].[Mem1].[All].Child",
           "[Dim3].[Mem1].&[1]"];

var res = _.chain(arr)
    .invoke("split", ".&")
    .groupBy(0)
    .map(function (els) {
        return "{ " + _.invoke(els, "join", ".&").join(", ") + " }";
    })
    .value();

console.log(res);
```

**this produces following output:**

```
[
"{ [Dim1].[Mem1].&[1], [Dim1].[Mem1].&[5] }", 
"{ [Dim2].[Mem1].&[2], [Dim2].[Mem1].&[77] }", 
"{ [Dim2].[Mem1].[All].Child }", 
"{ [Dim3].[Mem1].&[1] }"
]
```

The above code is using lodash library. It looks at the array and splits the values by `'.&'` and then groups the data by the resultant array's zero'th index.

This code is working fine and its doing whats its suppose to do.

Now consider a scenario where the input array does not have `'.&'` in it. In that case I want to split the input by `'.'` and then group the values. Is it possible to achieve the desired result by modifying code above? Or is it possible to do conditional split based on the input value?

```
var arrTwo = ["[Dim1].[Mem1].&[1]",
              "[Dim2].[Mem1].&[2]",
              "[Dim1].[Mem1].&[5]",
              "[Dim2].[Mem1].&[77]",
              "[Measures].[M11]",
              "[Dim2].[Mem1].[All].Child",
              "[Dim3].[Mem1].&[1]"],
              "[Measures].[M1]",
              "[Measures].[M2]";
```

**Expected output:**

```
[

"{ [Dim1].[Mem1].&[1], [Dim1].[Mem1].&[5] }" , 
"{ [Dim2].[Mem1].&[2], [Dim2].[Mem1].&[77] }", 
"{ [Dim2].[Mem1].[All].Child }", 
"{ [Dim3].[Mem1].&[1] }",
"{[Measures].[M11], [Measures].[M1], [Measures].[M2]}"
]
```

Comment: Why is the input data even formatted like that in the first place?
Do you have access to the way that's formed?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Thank you for reply. Can you please give me more information on what you meant by 'Why is the input data even formatted like that in the first place?' Did you mean why data is coming in format of [XXX].[YYY].&[ZZZ] ??

Comment: That's what I mean, yes. And can you change the format you receive the data in?
Also, what exactly do you want to result to look like?

Comment: @Cerbrus: I cannot change the format of the input data. The data is coming from another service (SSAS cube). I have added the expected result in the original question. I can get the result by using two function in first one I will split the value by '.&' and in second one by '.'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a regular expression in the `groupBy` callback instead of `split`:

```
var res = _.chain(arrTwo)
    .groupBy(function(x) {
        return x.match(/.+?\.&|[^.]+\./)[0]
    })
    .map(function (x) {
        return "{ " + x.join(", ") + " }";
    })
    .value();
```

This seems to produce the desired result: http://jsfiddle.net/aAy6L/2/

That regular expression first tries to match everything up to, and including, `.&`. If it fails (i.e. there's no `.&` in the string) it backtracks and tries to match "some non-dots and a dot". The found match is used as a `groupBy` key.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. This looks good. Can you please explain me how regular expression is working. i understand the remaining part but not what regular expression is doing.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite: added an explanation.